# populating a category axis in fxml file in javafx

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I have a `scatter chart`in a `fxml` file, and I want to add some values to its category axis. I want to do this in the `fxml` file. How can I add those values to my `category axis` in javafx?

```
<ScatterChart fx:id="scatterChart" title="title 1" titleSide="BOTTOM" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <xAxis  fx:id="xaxis">
        <NumberAxis lowerBound="-1.0" minorTickCount="0" side="BOTTOM" upperBound="1.0" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <CategoryAxis side="LEFT" />
    </yAxis  fx:id="yaxis">
</ScatterChart>
```

Comment: You don't add values to the axis (either in FXML or in Java). You add data to the chart, and the category axis displays values based on those data. Adding the data in FXML would be cumbersome, at best, and you are unlikely to want to do this in any real application (which will compute the data or read it from some external resource).

Comment: @James_D I have a fix chart that has the fixed Axes. Because of that I wanted to show the chart to the user and then I wanted to insert data to it.

Comment: OK, turns out this is possible after all. `CategoryAxis` has a `setCategories()` method taking an `ObservableList<String>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CategoryAxis` has a [`setCategories()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.html#setCategories-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) method taking an `ObservableList<String>`, so you need a `<categories>` element inside the `<CategoryAxis>` element. Creating and populating an `ObservableList<String>` takes a little digging into the [FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements), but basically you need `fx:factory` to create the list and `fx:value` to create the `String` instances:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>

<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>

<?import java.lang.String?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <ScatterChart fx:id="scatterChart" title="title 1"
            titleSide="BOTTOM" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <xAxis >
                <NumberAxis fx:id="xaxis" lowerBound="-1.0" minorTickCount="0" side="BOTTOM"
                    upperBound="1.0" />
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <CategoryAxis fx:id="yaxis" side="LEFT" >
                    <categories>
                        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                            <String fx:value="One"/>
                            <String fx:value="Two"/>
                            <String fx:value="Three" />
                            <String fx:value="Four" />
                            <String fx:value="Five" />                          
                        </FXCollections>
                    </categories>
                </CategoryAxis>
            </yAxis >
        </ScatterChart>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Test class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CategoryAxisExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ScatterChart.fxml")), 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use resource bundle strings via `%resourceId` in the fxml obsersvableList? E.g.: `<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList"><String fx:value="%test"/><FXCollections>`.
I tried this, but without success. Maybe there's another trick?